# How to create a RegExp pattern which start from the 1st character?

Tags: regex, uipath

I would like to apply this pattern but it doesnt work for me (in UiPath!). `(?<=^9000\s).*` https://regex101.com/r/1iyTEV/1 I need for example the row where the first number is 9000. Thanks for your answer, also for your time.

Comment: Use `(?m)(?<=^9000\s).*` or - if the lines are separated with CRLF and you do not want the CR to appear in the results use `(?m)(?<=^9000\s)[^\r\n]*`

Comment: May I kindly ask you to update the link? I just want to see your example.

Comment: [Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fm%29%28%3f%3c%3d%5e9000%5cs%29%5b%5e%5cr%5cn%5d*&i=1000+62+99000+String1+15%2c64+15%2c64%0d%0a1010+62+99000+String2+61%2c36+61%2c36%0d%0a7000+75+99000+String3+55%2c00+55%2c00%0d%0a7010+25+99000+44%2c00+44%2c00%0d%0a8010+99+36000+String5+33%2c60+33%2c60%0d%0a8050+99+35400+21%2c72+21%2c72%0d%0a9000+99+36400+String6+532%2c68+532%2c68%0d%0a9002+SUMME+13200%2c00+13200%2c00)

Comment: Ok, it's easier then I thought since (?<=\n9000\s).* works perfect. Thanks :)

Comment: But that won't match if the line is the first in the text.

Comment: Yes you are right, hopefully there is a header in the file! That's my luck. Have you tried my code in UiPath?

Comment: Wiktor, do you know how to match part of a row until the first number which contains a comma?

Comment: Probably `.*?(?=\d+\.\d)`